# Device debugging Defy Eclipse Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, usb

I am successfully using Eclipse with emulators. Now I want to use my Defy for device debugging, since the emulator is a bit slow.

My Defy has Cyanogenmod 7. My app is for 2.1 Android, so it should work. I followed all description and have device debugging set in my app manifest as well as the device settings.

If I type "adb devices", it now shows up one device. First I had problems with the driver with Win7 64Bit. After manual installation of the driver it worked.

I am wondering how to select the real device in Eclipse. In debug, I have my emulators. The real device does not show up in the list of my emulators. It is not an emulator so it makes sense. But how can a Start debugging on it. Or shall I copy the apk on the device and somehow attach Eclipse to the running process for debugging?

Best Regards,

Patrick

---

I do not get my Defy debugging in Eclipse. Some days ago it had worked. I just restarted my laptop and found the below error. adb is installed under the requested path. If I type adb devices in cmd in that path I get a device: efefeSOME_NUMBERrggr offline, Do not know if the offine is a problem

I also tries the wifi adb apps. If i connect with this tools I also get a device 192.168...:5555 device. This looks good.

After trying again eclipse debug, it directly starts the debugger. I have switched on enable debug, my phone is rootet. Can anyone give me a hint, what I may also consider? It had worked one day and now it does not.

[2012-04-12 22:10:01 - MyApp] ------------------------------ [2012-04-12 22:10:01 - MyApp] Android Launch! [2012-04-12 22:10:01 - MyApp] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured. [2012-04-12 22:10:01 - MyApp] You must restart adb and Eclipse. [2012-04-12 22:10:01 - MyApp] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\Entwicklung\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download the USB Driver from Motorola here [USB DRIVER](http://www.motorola.com/Support/DE-DE/Support-Homepage/Software-and-Drivers/USB-and-PC-Charging-Drivers)

then USB debugging like "Waqas" says and i also use Unknow Sources. I Develop with a Motorola Defy 2.1 and it works fine :-D

...sorry i read you question to fast. Maybe try this go in Eclipse to Run->Run Configurations and set the Target to Manual. Then you should be able to chouse your device

Comment: Thank you for your proposals. I got it running again. I downloaded eclipse new and set the android plugins again. Now it is working fine. Also the Wifi debugging, which is really nice.

Comment: if my awnser helps you to solve the problem, i would looking farward if you accept it as right :-) thx

Answer (score 3):

I have been learning Android by developing under Windows 7, Eclipse and the emulator. I wanted to start using my old LG Adroid instead of the emulator, but a soon as I plugged it in and did all the stuff to get it working with ADB, Eclipse blew up with : Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.

If I unplug the phone, Eclipse will start up the emulator and work just fine. I found that if I first do a "adb shell" and then exit the shell, Eclipse is happy and works.

I need to do this on every reboot of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable **USB Debugging** mode in your device's setting to allow eclipse (ADT) to use it for development.

> Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB debugging (should be
>   enables)